# How to call controller function from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angular and i am trying to call controller function from directive. But not getting idea that what is a proper way to make a call back function. Here is my javascript

directive:

```
    angular.module("myApp").directive('contenteditable', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('blur change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
                scope.editTranslation(element.attr('data-ng-model'));
            });
         });

        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
    }
}
 });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http, $log) 
  {
   $scope.editTranslation = function (flagTranslation)         {
   console.log(flagTranslation);};
```

HTML:

```
<tr class="statistics_table_row cursor" data-ng-repeat="ft in flagsWithTranslation">
  <td contenteditable="true" ng-model="ft.translation" >{{ ft.translation }}</td></tr>
```

What i am trying basically after setting model value directive call a controller function scope.editTranslation() by given a model as parameter. Can someone help me on this

Comment: I am getting flagTranslation as undefined value in  $scope.editTranslation = function (flagTranslation) {}

Comment: the attribute value will only pass the string `"ft.translation"` to function. what exctly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by adding  scope: { 'ctrlFn' : '&'}, in a directive. Here is my working code:

```
.directive('contenteditable', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: { 'ctrlFn' : '&'},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('blur change', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
                scope.editTranslation(element.attr('data-ng-model'));
            });
         });

        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
    }
}
});
```

HTML:

```
  <td contenteditable="true" ctrl-fn="ctrlFn(ft)" ng-model="ft.translation"
```